# How can I award a bounty to a particular answer?

Tags: support, bounties

I have a question which is already asked on Stack Overflow, and I found one of the answers to be useful to me. How can I award a bounty to a particular answer?

Comment: Just as you would with a regular bounty. But when choosing a reason, choose the option to award it to an existing answer.

Comment: You can award bounty on any answer you want